# Scaling down lat/lon polygon?

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, algorithm

I have a set of (lat,lon) coordinates that compose a polygon.

Is there a straightforward method to get an analogous set of coordinates defining a smaller version of the polygon?

For example, given the following picture:

[image]

If I am provided with the set of coordinates defining the blue shape, how can I obtain the set of coordinates corresponding to the green one?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: no software, I am implementing a program in Java and I need to define a polygon and obtain its smaller version

Comment: If you don't wanna code it yourself, you'll probably want a buffer function, using a negative buffer width.

Answer (score 1):

Jts is a geometry library for java. Its geometry class has a buffer function. Here is a description of the api: https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html
Source code is available, too.